# Измерение расстояние прокрутки страницы вниз

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Всем привет! Задача заключается в следующем, есть блок с фильтрами. При прокрутке страницы вниз, до верхней границы этого блока становится position: fixed. Я измеряю расстояние от верха страницы до границы блока следующим образом:

```
// В моем случае примерно 80px;
var offsetFromScreenTop = $(".collapsing-container").offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();
```

Все прекрасно работает, но проблема заключается в следующим: когда страница была промотана вниз, предположим на 200px и страница обновлена F5, то происходит новый перерасчет и я получаю 280px, и мое меню меняет класс гораздо ниже чем я закладывал.

Вот остальная часть кода:
`

```
this.scrolled = window.scrollY > offsetFromScreenTop;
var temp_width = $('.collapsing-container').outerWidth()
if (this.scrolled)  { 
    $('.collapsing-container').addClass('Fixed');
} else {
    console.log('меньше' + offsetFromScreenTop);
    $('.collapsing-container').removeClass('Fixed');
    $('.collapsing-container').css('width', temp_width);
}
```

`

Comment: Не очень понятно. Сделайте, плиз, пример целиком на https://jsfiddle.net например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***>>При прокрутке страницы вниз, до верхней границы этого блока становится position: fixed***

Это похоже на то, что мы называем липкими блоками: в какой-то момент блок поддается скроллированию вместе со всей страницей, а в какой-то момент прилипает к окну браузера. Все верно?

Если вам позволено проигнорировать эту функциональность в Internet Explorer (не в Edge, в Edge уже все ок), то, вероятно вас спасет **position: sticky** и можно обойтись вообще без скриптов. Работать будет значительно лучше, не будет видимых скачков (особенно на смартфонах), не будет багов, не надо ничего считать и программировать. В IE тем временем сделайте обычный absolute или fixed -- вариант попроще.

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант, но не прилипло, вешал на родителя sticky. Пробовал на mozile, chrome. Не знаю с чем это может быть связанно. У меня в проекте плагиновая система может из-за этого, хотя один в другой вложен и иерархия по верстки есть.

Comment: Про плагиновую систему не оч. понятно, но position: sticky должно работать. Оно же существует не просто так :)
Если вам подходит, то почитайте про него поглубже, изучите особенности. Там, насколько я помню, нужно чтобы у ни у каких родителей липкого блока не было задано свойство overflow. Проверьте что есть контекст в котором блок будет залипать (родитель с конкретной высотой). Сделайте демку вне проекта просто с нуля чтобы попробовать.

Comment: Спасибо заработало, моя ошибка была в том что был еще контейнер прослойка, и я ее по началу не заметил, через консоль разработчика. А через html файл(каждый файл это отдельный plugin) не удобно смотреть поскольку идет череда наследование и вложенностей, в любом случае получилось, спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

Привел к такому виду и все заработало как я хотел.

```
var offsetFromScreenTop = $(".collapsing-container").offset().top
```